# Change scrollbar position as fixed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the table with values more than 50 rows in my project. If I'm in the middle of the table I can't able to visible the scrollbar to scroll vertically.

As per the below example when I scroll the page down I want **top vertical scrollbar to be fixed**.

Anyone help to me achieve the scrollbar in fixed position when page scroll down. Let me know if you have any queries.

**Before scroll:**
[image: scroll-image]

**After scroll:**
[image: scroll the page down2]

```js
$(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper2")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper1")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
    width: 800px;
    border: none 0px RED;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.wrapper1 {
    height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 20px;
}
.div2 {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #88ff88;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="div2">
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
        <p>
            aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As an aside to the question, why are you not using a `table` for your table data?

Comment: I am not really sure but this might be useful for you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-position-sticky

Comment: I don't think changing scroll bar position is practically possible.. One work around is to create and element which you can use to mimic the action of scrollbar using js. or button at both end to scroll left and right.. if you want that example i will provide the code

Comment: @Amalnandan yes go ahead. provide me some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give `wrapper1` class `position: fixed` property and your problem will be solved

Comment: I get your point , and answer is updated , i wish your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of scrolling using button. and Button can be positioned fixed so that it dont get scrolled

**To scroll**

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper2').scrollLeft += 40; //Right

document.querySelector('.wrapper2').scrollLeft -= 40; //left
```

**To get smooth effect**

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

```js
const buttonRight = document.getElementById('scrollright');
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('scrollleft');
buttonRight.onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.wrapper2').scrollLeft += 40;
};
buttonLeft.onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.wrapper2').scrollLeft -= 40;
};
```

```css
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
  width: 800px;
  border: none 0px RED;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.wrapper1 {
  height: 20px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: #88ff88;
  overflow: auto;
}

#scrollleft {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

#scrollright {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav-btn ">
  <button class="" id="scrollleft">&lt;</button>
  <button class="" id="scrollright">&gt;</button>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="div2">
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
    <p>
      aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```